# Trigonometry when to divide and times

Tags: trigonometry, education

OK, so I am revising for an upcoming test and am a bit confused. I have previously learn Trigonometry, however that was around a year ago, and i have completely forgotten it now. I went on to MathsWatch, which is an online revision website. I am currently going through the three trigonometry clips on there (Clips 147a, 147b and 147c). On clip 147a they teach a divisible method [image: Here division is used]

However, on Clip 147b they teach it using a multiplication method, as follows: [image]

I cannot, for the life of me, remember as to why two different methods are used. Any explanations?

Comment: They use the same equation. Look closely, 2nd equation in the first pic is the same equation in the 2nd pic 3rd line.

Answer (score 1):

They use the same equation. What is causing the confusion is the way they depict the formulas. In the first pic, the triangle "shows" the equation as

**Equation 1**: $A$ = $\cos c$ $*$$H$

while the second pic says:

**Equation 2:** $\cos c$ = $A$$\div$$H$

Since you are trying to find side A, you have to re-arrange the formulas to solve for A.

In the first pic your equation is already solving for side A so you dont need to rearrange **Equation 1**.

For the second pic, you have to re-arrange **Equation 2** to solve for A.

**Equation 2:** $\cos$ c = $A$$\div$$H$

$\cos c$ $*$ $H$ = $A$$\div$$H$ * $H$   Multiplying both sides by **H**

$A$ = $\cos c$ $*$ $H$ <--This is the same as **Equation 1**